# jquery selector isnt working when trying to NOT include something

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I am trying to do a slideToggle when i click on a tr, which expands some hidden content.  Current, when i do it, it will shutter/blink, opening and closing 4 times.  What i am trying to do it make it so that ALL children except div#bounds(and by association, all the children of it) will gain that onclick attribute.

```
<tr id="attr_expander"><th>Alignment</th><td><input class="attribute" type ="text" disabled="true" />
    <div id="bounds">
       <label><input type="radio" name="toggle" value = "1"><span></span></label>
       <label><input type="radio" name="toggle" value="2"><span></span></label>
       <label><input type="radio" name="toggle" value = "4"><span></span></label><br />
       <label><input type="radio" name="toggle"value = "16"><span></span></label>
       <label><input type="radio" name="toggle"value = "32"><span></span></label>
       <label><input type="radio" name="toggle"value = "64"><span></span></label><br />
       <label><input type="radio" name="toggle"value = "256"><span></span></label>
       <label><input type="radio" name="toggle"value = "512"><span></span></label>
       <label><input type="radio" name="toggle"value = "1024"><span></span></label>
    </div>
```

​

the jquery is:

```
$("#attr_expander").find("*:not(div[id='bounds'])").click(function () {
    $("#bounds").slideToggle();
});
```

css to make things looking a bit better:

```
#bounds {
    margin:4px;
    background-color:#EFEFEF;
    border-radius:4px;
    border:1px solid #D0D0D0;
    overflow:auto;
    float:left;
}

#bounds label {
    float:left;
    width:2.25em;
    height:3.0em;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#bounds label span {
    text-align:center;
    padding:3px 0px;
    display:block;

    width:2.25em;
    height:2.75em;
}

#bounds label span:hover
{
    background-color:Aqua;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#bounds label input {
    position:absolute;
    top:-20px;
}

#bounds input:checked + span {
    background-color:#404040;
    color:#F7F7F7;
}​
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#attr_expander").find('*').not('#bounds, #bounds *').click(function () {
    $("#bounds").slideToggle();
});
```

[**Working example**](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/ntXjQ/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just check to see what the target of the click event was, and only do the toggle if the nodename was a table cell?

```
$("#attr_expander").click(function (e) {
    if((e.target.nodeName)=="TH" || (e.target.nodeName)=="TD") $("#bounds").slideToggle();
});​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/G3tnQ/1/)**.

Answer (score 0):

You could just bind to the element, then check if `#bounds` is one of the parents. This way, you are only binding one event listener, instead of one per element.

http://jsfiddle.net/G3tnQ/3/

```
$("#attr_expander").on('click', function (e) {
    var bounds = '#bounds',
        $target = $(e.target);

    if (!$target.is(bounds) && $target.closest(bounds).length === 0) {
        $(bounds).slideToggle();
    }
});​
```